# Memory management bug in formatter class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have followed all the rules of memory management but can someone explain to me why this is causing a double free exception:

```
- (NSString *)formattedStringWithDecimal:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0]; //zero deimal spaces
    [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp]; //round up

    return [[formatter stringFromNumber:decimalNumber] autorelease];
}
```

This is how I am calling it:

```
//Set the label of the cell formatting the distance from the device 
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@ miles", 
                               selectedAirport.name, [self formattedStringWithDecimal:selectedAirport.milesFromDevice]];
```

I have subsequently changed it to this which now works - however I still don't know what I did wrong in the first piece of code.

```
- (NSString *)formattedStringWithDecimal:(NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumber
{
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0]; //zero deimal spaces
    [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp]; //round up

    NSString *result = [NSString stringWithString:[formatter stringFromNumber:decimalNumber]];
    [formatter release];
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `stringFromNumber:` returns an autoreleased string. In the first method, that returned string is being autoreleased a second time. Also, in the first method, `formatter` was never being released. In short, the string was being released an extra time and the formatter was leaking.

The second method looks much better. Perhaps there was some confusion between releasing `formatter` and releasing the string returned by `stringFromNumber:`. The line:

```
return [[formatter stringFromNumber:decimalNumber] autorelease];
```

sends the `autorelease` message to the string produced by `[formatter stringFromNumber:decimalNumber]`, not to the formatter itself.